# Modal Component use

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to use the modal component to manage the alert in the app.

I have wrote an example code to try how it works:

import Modal from "react-native-modal";

```
export default class ModalTester extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            feedback: "",
        }
        state = {
          isModalVisible: false
        };
    }

  check() {
      let ctrl = true;
        if (ctrl == true){
        this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });
      }
    else {
        this.stopConnection();
    }
  }

  stopConnection() {
    console.log("stop Connection.")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Button title="Stop" onPress={() => this.check()} />
        <Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible} style={alignItem = "center"}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center"}}>
            <Text>Check your level:</Text>
            <Image 
                style={{width:30, height:30}} 
                source={require('../Image/logo.png')}
                onPress={() => this.setState({feedback: 'N', isModalVisible: false}),this.stopConnection() }/>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Basically I would when the stop button is clicked show this modal component with a image and when the user click on the image set a variable feedback to N and go in the stopConnection function (I insert only a console log to try the functionality).

I don't understand why the image is unclickable. So I don't go in the function stopConnection when it's clicked.

Also the component stay open and I have tried to use isModalVisible: false to close the component when the image is clicked, but it doesn't work.

How can I do? Thank you

Comment: You're mixing a class field called `this.state` with a local constructor variable called `state`.

Comment: take a look at your state

Comment: You should bind `check` in constructor `this.check = this.check.bind(this)`.

Comment: @techouse So I should put state = {isModalVisibile..} outside the constructor??

Comment: You should have combined state like `this.state = {
            feedback: "",
            isModalVisible: false,
        };`

Comment: @ravibagul91 Thank you for your reply, while for the rest of code?

Comment: Your onPress should be this `onPress={() => this.setState({feedback: 'N', isModalVisible: false});this.stopConnection() }`

Comment: There is an error with the "; "

Comment: Try this `onPress={() => { this.setState({feedback: 'N', isModalVisible: false});this.stopConnection();} }`